# Php page shows parse error in line 9 on the below code kindly help to solve this issue

Tags: php, parsing, error-handling

[image]

on the above image line shows a parse error kindly help me to solve the issue.

Comment: where is the Code Dude?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and paste the code into your question. Your code should be readable formatted. For more information see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **|** in namespace name in PHP. If you want to split namespace into segments, they should be separated with **backslash**.

Replace

```
namespace |integration_name|API;
```

with

```
namespace \integration_name\API;
```

Comment: I tried with \ also but it show the same parse error like syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: <?php


error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

require_once('../../../lib/class.|integration_name|api.php');

use |integration_name|API\|integration_name|_api as |integration_name|api;


$user = "user";

$password = "password";

$api_base = "https://mediamath.endpoint.com/";
$integration_name\api_object = new \integration_name\api("null",$api_base,1);
$login_result = $\integration_name\api_object->login($user,$password);
print_r($login_result);
?> this page line no 8 shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

Comment: The problem is with "|" around "integration_name" - you cannot have that in namespace declaration